# Usage of -> and what Kind of Construct is this, please?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have seen one example code fragment, but to be honest, I do not know anything about the code construct used:

```
just_the_files = (dataTransfer) ->
real_files_set = {}
for item in dataTransfer.items
    entry = item.getAsEntry?() or item.webkitGetAsEntry?() or item
    if entry.isFile
        real_files_set[entry.name] = true
 (file for file in dataTransfer.files when file.name of real_files_set)
```

I have never seen usage of such code fragment before, especially use of `->` in JavaScript. If you tell me how is it called, so I can study it, please. Thanks.

This is the source of the code fragment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612729/478569

Comment: It seems to be [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), not pure javascript.

Comment: this looks like [coffescript](http://coffeescript.org/).

Comment: It's definitely not native JavaScript. Neither is `or`, or `when`.

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12612729), right?

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. I have edited my question and provided the source of the code fragment. I have explicitly checked, if it says something about JavaScript and it does not. It may be something else, indeed.

Comment: @parchment, hi, yes exactly, that is the source.

Comment: your `just_the_files` function is an empty function. coffeescript is whitespace sensitive (like python). if you want the rest of the code to execute inside this function, you have to indent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a coffeescript function.

In javascript:

```
var f = function (x) {
    doSomething();
};
```

In coffeescript:

```
f = (x) ->
    doSomething()
```

http://coffeescript.org/